# Karate DSL surefire - reports duplicated time

Tags: karate

In my work, we implemented a lot le features that call another feature because de reuse scenarios for many scenarios.

But, when see the html reporte, this one show 5 minutes execution when, in console said 2.5 minutes.

We found in sunfire reports that the time of the feature son, the step that call a web service delay 30 ms, but also the step that call this feature son has 30 ms. So is 60 ms.

## feature parent

- call (feature Son.feature) 30ms

  ## this is the son
- given url                   0 ms
- where status 200   30 ms

## feature report

Column duration 60 ms

Excuse me por my bad english. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things.

1. If you use the parallel runner, you will see different time (actual / elapsed)
2. When you call features, just focus on the time reported by the parent

Can you refer this video, so you can troubleshoot better: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1049321708241317888

Comment: Peter, thanks, yes, the problem is that the html reports show the duration off all steps and is not reliable information.

Comment: @SamuelChong feel free to ask for a feature request, but you have to follow this process, even now I am not clear which report you are referring to: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue